# How to set time interval using date time picker control in xpage

Tags: xpages

I want to set a time interval of 15 minute using date time picker control .
When selecting time by clicking on upward key.
where as in lotus domino server 8.5.3 default increasing time is 5 minute and in lotus domino server 9 it is increasing by 1 min.
Can anybody help me how to set?

Answer (score 0):

There aren't any options on the xp:dateTimeHelper tag to set that 15min interval for the date-time-both picker control.
In the absence of an official way to do it, you could try using the smallDelta option on the relevant sub-part of the control, but it isn't future-proof, as changes in the control implementation could break this code, and I haven't tested it thoroughly. Also the defaultValue here would need to be implemented.

Example of setting the smallDelta on the TimeSpinner part of the date-time-both control:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core">
    <xp:inputText id="inputText1" value="#{viewScope.value1}">
        <xp:this.converter>
            <xp:convertDateTime type="both"></xp:convertDateTime>
        </xp:this.converter>
        <xp:this.defaultValue><![CDATA[#{javascript://
            // TODO set default time to current-time modulo 15min,
            // to prevent use of un-mod'd now time,
            // which leads to time interval options like:
            //  4:03, 4:18, 4:33, 4:48, etc
        //}]]></xp:this.defaultValue>
        <xp:dateTimeHelper></xp:dateTimeHelper>
    </xp:inputText>
    <xp:scriptBlock id="scriptBlock1">
        <xp:this.value><![CDATA[//
        //Modify the behavior of all TimeSpinners on the page
        require(["ibm/xsp/widget/layout/TimeSpinner"], function(timeSpinner){
            // arrow keys delta:
            timeSpinner.prototype.smallDelta = 15; // 15min
            // page up/down delta:
            timeSpinner.prototype.largeDelta = 180; // 3hours
        });
        //]]></xp:this.value>
    </xp:scriptBlock>
</xp:view>
```